# MONGO- Consulta a documentos

Tags: javascript, nodejs, base-de-datos, web, mongodb

Estoy intentando hacer una consulta a MongoDB, pero estoy teniendo un problema: cuando hago la consulta si el registro no tiene alguno de los campos con los que hago la consulta me regresa un arreglo vacío.

En este caso el campo `segundoApellido`, cuando uso `$exists` si me  regresa el registro cuando lo busco por `id`.

¿Hay alguna forma de decirle a mongo que me devuelva el documento aun si no tiene el campo `segundoApellido`?

Estoy creando el siguiente objeto para la consulta

```js
let servidorBuscado = {
  "id": { $regex: new RegExp(query.id, "i") },
  "servidorPublicoSancionado.curp": { $regex: new RegExp(query.curp, "i") },
  "servidorPublicoSancionado.nombres": { $regex: new RegExp(query.nombres, "i") },
  "institucionDependencia.nombre": { $regex: new RegExp(query.institucionDependencia, "i") },
  "servidorPublicoSancionado.primerApellido": { $regex: new RegExp(query.primerApellido, "i") },
  //"servidorPublicoSancionado.segundoApellido": { $regex: new RegExp(query.segundoApellido, "i") }
  "servidorPublicoSancionado.segundoApellido": { $exists: false }
}
```

Ahí se puede apreciar que la línea comentada causa conflicto, pues el registro que busco por `id` no tiene el campo `segundoApellido`.

Este es el código de la consulta:

```js
servidores = await ServidorSancionado.find(servidorBuscado,
  {
    "servidorPublicoSancionado.rfc": 0,
    "servidorPublicoSancionado.curp": 0
  })
.sort(sortConsulta)
.collation({ 'locale': 'es' })
.skip((pageSize * page) - pageSize)
.limit(pageSize);
```

Answer (score 1):

Usar $or.

```
$or: [
    {
    "servidorPublicoSancionado.segundoApellido": { $regex: new RegExp(query.segundoApellido, "i")
    },
    {
    "servidorPublicoSancionado.segundoApellido": {$eq: null}
    }
]
```

Comment: Funciona cuando busco por otro atributo como nombre por ejemplo, pero al buscar por el segundoApellido me devuelve registros que no coinciden con la búsqueda, ademas necesito hacer lo mismo para todos los demas campos ya que todos pueden no estar en el registro